# Finding smallest circle enclosing all points given their $x,y$-coordinates?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, circles, problem-solving

I have an algorithm that I think calculates the minimum radius of all points in the list, which runs in $O(n)$ time and is incredibly easy to implement, but is it correct? If so, has it been invented before? It is not described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem).

The algorithm, given a list of all points with $x,y$-coordinates, is as follows:

1. Get average of all $x$ and $y$ coordinates in the list in order to get the center of the circle $(\frac1n(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n), \frac1n(y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_n))$.
2. Calculate the distance between all the points from the center using $d((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_2 − x_1)^2 + (y_2 − y_1)^2}$, to find the point with maximum distance from the average point. So, this distance will be the minimum radius to cover all points.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The algorithm you proposed sounds similar to the algorithm described [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320700/is-this-solution-to-the-fifth-question-in-primes-2022-valid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm is very simple because it doesn't always work.

Suppose we are given the points $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(6,0)$. Your algorithm will first average them to get the point $(3,0)$, then compute a maximum distance of $3$. However, a better solution is to take a circle with center $(3.5,0)$ and radius $2.5$.

Comment: In general, if you have a cluster of points close together, and a lone point far away, the proposed algorithm will give a center too close to the cluster.

Comment: Yet it might be an interesting way to minimize the effect of outliers without the need to discriminate which points are outliers.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri: No. If you want to minimize the effect of outliers, you need to **remove** them before running whatever algorithm you want.